# How to get difference in time from current time and database? And d i want to send email one hour before time in database arrive in php?

Tags: php, mysql

how do i get the diffence in time from mysql database and current time. I have tried the below.

```
$time_db ="SELECT `start`FROM `bookings`";
               $w = $conn->query($nam);
               if ($w->num_rows > 0)
                      {
                       while($row = $w->fetch_assoc())
                          {
                             $Current_time=time();
                             $time_from_db=$row['start'];
                          }
                   }
               if($time_from_db-$Current_time<=time(1:00)
                 {
                   //send email
                 }
```

Comment: `SELECT TIMEDIFF(start, NOW())`

Comment: Thanks guys, i got i used this query SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,CURRENT_TIME,start) as hours FROM bookings"

Answer (score 0):

Do not fetch whole table to find relevant rows, instead let MySQL to calculate it for you:

```
$breaking_time=  time() - 60*60; // 1 hour ago

$time_db ="SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE `start` < ".gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", breaking_time);

$w = $conn->query($nam);
if ($w->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $w->fetch_assoc()) {
          //send email
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i got i used this query `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,CURRENT_TIME,start) as hours FROM bookings"`